# Server/client program behaves different after adding code in C

Tags: c, file, sockets

I'm on Windows. I have a server/client program that copies a file from client to server. Everthing works as expected until I add the code where I send the size of the file from client to server. When I remove the code it works fine again. The `while()` loop in my server normally loops `378` times the `while()` loop in my client also loops `378` times. After I add the code to send the file size the `while()` loop in my server loops `377` times, and that causes the failure. I don't get any errors but when I click on the copied file it doesn't show anything(because the server loops `377` instead of `378`). I commented `***` where the code is that I'm talking about. What is the cause of this and how can I solve it?

Edit: The server receives the size of the file successfully

functions:

```
int getSizeFile(FILE* file)
{
    // get file size
    FILE *f = file;
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sizeFile = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    return sizeFile;
}
static inline uint32_t ntohl_ch(char const* X)
{
    uint32_t x; memcpy(&x, X, sizeof(x));
    return ntohl(x);
}
```

server:

```
char ch[70];
printf("where do you want to save it(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", ch, 70);

char c[70];
printf("which file you want to copy(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", c, 70);

r = send(s, c, 70, 0); // B
if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("2 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
}

FILE* copyFile;
fopen_s(&copyFile, ch, "wb");
if (copyFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}

char buf[BUFSIZE];
size_t size = BUFSIZE;
int counter = 0;

// *** receiving file size. This is the code
char b[8192];
r = recv(s, b, 8192, 0); // C
if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("error recv\n");
}
uint32_t test = ntohl_ch(&b[0]);
printf("%d\n", (int)test);
// *** Until here

while (1)
{
    int res = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("3 error %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
        break;
    }
    size = fwrite(buf, 1, res, copyFile);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
    printf("res: %d\n", res);
    counter++;
    printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
}
fclose(copyFile);
```

client:

```
                char c[70];
                res = recv(ClientSocket, c, 70, 0); // B
                if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("Server disconeccted\n");
                    break;
                }
                
                FILE* originalFile;
                fopen_s(&originalFile, c, "rb");
                if (originalFile == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error opening file\n");
                }

                char buf[BUFSIZE];
                size_t size = BUFSIZE;
                int counter = 0;

                // getting file size
                int sizeFile = getSizeFile(originalFile);

                // *** sending file size. This is the code
                uint32_t num = htonl(sizeFile);
                char* converted_num = (char*)&num;
                res = send(ClientSocket, converted_num, sizeof(num), 0); // C
                if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    printf("error send\n");
                }
                // *** Until here

                while (size == BUFSIZE)
                {
                    size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, originalFile);
                    int r = send(ClientSocket, buf, size, 0);
                    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        printf("1 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
                        break;
                    }
                    printf("size: %d\n", size);
                    printf("r: %d\n", r);
                    counter++;
                    printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
                }
                printf("out of while loop\n");
                fclose(originalFile);
```

Comment: It probably receives the first part of the file at the same time it receives the file size. And your server throws away that part of the file.

Comment: `memcpy(&x, X, sizeof(x));` Using upper case and lower case letters as variable names like this is literally asking for trouble.

Comment: To @user253751 's point, `r = recv(s, b, 8192, 0);` ? Do you really need to read up to 8192 bytes to get the *four* octets needed for obtaining the size ? A *debugger*, a breakpoint on the line immediately after that, and examination of the value of `r` would be informative, I suspect.

Comment: @WhozCraig r returns 516. I changed 8192 to 516 but still it doesn't work

Comment: @user253751 What can I do instead of this?

Comment: @l9a1 Do you understand that means you read 516 bytes of data from the client in that call?

Comment: @user253751 yes, so I'm reading too much.

Comment: @user253751 What should the number be? how can i decide that?

Comment: @i9a1 how many bytes of data do you want that call to read?

Comment: @user253751 i guess sizeof uint32_t

Comment: Exactly. And make *sure* you got that many bytes before trying the conversion, and no *more* than that many bytes.

Comment: it works now, i thought it was good practice to make the buffers extra large

Comment: only if you want to receive an extra-large amount of data. It's not one send to one recv - all the bytes from all the sends run together and you can recv any number of them at once

Comment: So I have to always recv the same amount as I send?